# How do I call a function to a main function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a main function containing a dictionary. I also a have another function in which I have to access the dictionary in the main function in order for the function to work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
def main():

    # initial roster
    brave_roster = {
        "Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273",
        "Ronald Acuna": "AB: 467, R: 71, H: 124, HR: 15, AVG: 0.266",
    }

    # your code here 

    print("\t ***  Braves Stats!  ***\n")
    print("Welcome to My Braves Stats! What can I do for you?\n")
    print('  1. Search for a player')
    print('  2. Add a new player')
    print('  3. Remove a player')
    choice = int(input("Please type your choice number:"))
    #player_look = input("Enter the name of the player you want to look up:")


#call functions
if __name__ == '__main__':
    player_look = lookup_player(brave_roster)

main()


def lookup_player(brave_roster,choice):

  player_look = input("Enter the name of the player you want to look up:")

  if choice == 1:
      print(player_look)
      print(player_look,"Here are Austin's stats:", 
brave_roster["Austin Riley"])
  elif choice == 1:
      print(player_look)
      print("Here are Ronald's stats", 
brave_roster["Ronald Acuna"])
  else:
      choice == False
      print("N/A")
  

  return brave_roster(player_look)


print("Thanks for using my Braves Stats.")
```

I've tried using the `if __name__ == '__main__'` condition, but my other function is undefined.

Comment: There's no `lookup_player()` function definition.

Comment: @Barmar I justed added the def.

Comment: you call lookup_player before you define it -- also, 'brave_roster' is not defined where you pass it

Comment: As comment above  says, you do not have a lookup_player function defined. But to answer your question, you cannot access a variable defined in a function or method from outside the function/method. You must declare the variable globally (outside any function) or alternatively start with the variable declared in main and pass that variable as an argument to the lookup function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What do you mean by "call to"? maybe "call from"? Please [edit] to clarify. And when you say "main file", do you mean "main function"? Check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips on making the question clear, like providing a [mre].

Comment: @harriet can you explain what you mean by "not defined where I pass it"? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: brave_roster is only defined in main the way you've written it -- it is not in the same scope. You also cannot even call lookup_player because you've defined it beneath the line of code that calls it.

Answer (score 2):

Python is an interpreter language which means it executes code line by line.

Your code is completely fine but the place you call this function is incorrect:

```
#call functions
if __name__ == '__main__':
    player_look = lookup_player(brave_roster)
```

When Python comes to `player_look = lookup_player(brave_roster)`, the `lookup_player()` has not been defined yet. You will see an error.

Plus you used **brave_roster** dictionary inside of main function so it is the property of main function and main function does not share its property with anyone else there for you need to bring out **brave_roster** dictionary outside...

To fix this, move the whole condition to the end of the program.

Comment: *"Your code is completely fine"* -- Um, did you try running it? It eventually crashes with `NameError: name 'brave_roster' is not defined`, and there are more problems beyond that too.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the user input in `main()` and pass both the name and choice to `lookup_player`. Also, your return statement, `brave_roster(player_look)`, needed to use brackets to access the dict value. In the case below, you'd call `brave_roster[name]` but if you wanted to return that, it'd have to be within the 'else' where we know the name is in the roster: `assert(name in brave_roster)`. Otherwise, you will get a KeyError.

```
def lookup_player(brave_roster, name, choice):
    if name not in brave_roster:
        if choice == 2:
            brave_roster[name] = "stats"
            print("Added {n} from the roster.".format(n=name))
        else:
            print("Name not in roster.")
    else:
        assert(name in brave_roster)
        if choice == 1:
            print("Here are {n}'s stats:".format(n=name))
            print(brave_roster[name])
        elif choice == 3:
            del brave_roster[name]
            print("Removed {n} from the roster.".format(n=name))
        else:
            print("N/A")
    # TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
    # change brave_roster(player_look) to brackets
    return


def main():
    print("\t ***  Braves Stats!  ***\n")
    print("Welcome to My Braves Stats! What can I do for you?\n")
    print('  1. Search for a player')
    print('  2. Add a new player')
    print('  3. Remove a player')
    name = input("Enter the name of the player you want to look up:")
    choice = int(input("Please type your choice number:"))
    return name, choice


# call functions
if __name__ == '__main__':
    name, choice = main()
    brave_roster = {
        "Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273",
        "Ronald Acuna": "AB: 467, R: 71, H: 124, HR: 15, AVG: 0.266",
    }
    player_look = lookup_player(brave_roster, name, choice)
    print("Thanks for using my Braves Stats.")
```

Comment: Thank you Harriet! I appreciate the visual aid. For each choice: to look up, add, and remove, I have to have three individual functions. Your program did help clear up somethings.